# How do I number the nodes, if they are sometimes different elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I need to number the nodes that contain data (xml) using xsl transformation. Nodes that are numbered, may have elements with different tag names. 
I was looking for a solution to this, but I could not find a proper way of numbering.

Here is a sample input file:

```
       <Contract>
        <Parametr1>
            <Interposes>
                   <Accomplice>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>John</Name>
                           <Surname>Person1</Surname>
                    </Person>
                   </Accomplice>
                <Representative>
                    <Name>George</Name>
                    <Surname>Person2</Surname>
                   </Representative>
            </Interposes>
            <Interposes>
                <Accomplice>
                    <Person>
                        <Name>Andy</Name>
                        <Surname>Person3</Surname>
                    </Person>
                </Accomplice>
            </Interposes>
            <Interposes>
                <Accomplice>
                    <Firm>
                        <FirmName>VeloDrom</FirmName>
                        <Description>Description</Description>
                    </Firm>
                </Accomplice>
                <Representative>
                    <Name>Agnes</Name>
                    <Surname>Person4</Surname>
                </Representative>
                <Representative>
                    <Name>Michael</Name>
                    <Surname>Person5</Surname>
                </Representative>
            </Interposes>
        </Parametr1>
       </Contract>
```

The correct result should look like this:

> 1. George Person2 representing a person: John Person1
> 2. Andy Person3
> 3. Agnes Person4 representing a firm: VeloDrom Description
> 4. Michael Person5 representing a firm: VeloDrom Description

My attempt to solve the (unsuccessful):

```
      <xsl:template match="Contract">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="Parametr1"/>
      </xsl:template>


      <xsl:template match="Parametr1">

          <xsl:apply-templates select="Interposes/Accomplice/Person"/>

          <xsl:apply-templates select="Interposes/Representative"/>

      </xsl:template>


      <xsl:template match="Interposes/Accomplice/Person | Interposes/Representative">
          <xsl:number format="1. " count="Interposes/Accomplice/Person | Interposes/Representative"/>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="count(./Interposes/Representative)=0">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="Interposes/Accomplice/Person"/>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="count(./Interposes/Representative) &gt; 0">
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
              <xsl:value-of select="./Name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="./Surname"/>
            <xsl:if test="count(../Representative) &gt; 0">
              <xsl:if test="../Accomplice/Person">
                <xsl:text>, representing a person: </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="../Accomplice/Person/Name"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                   <xsl:value-of select="../Accomplice/Person/Surname"/>
                 </xsl:if>
                 <xsl:if test="../Accomplice/Firm">
                   <xsl:text>, representing a firm: </xsl:text>
                   <xsl:value-of select="../Accomplice/Firm/FirmName"/><xsl:text> </xsl:text>
                   <xsl:value-of select="../Accomplice/Firm/Description"/>
                 </xsl:if>
               </xsl:if>
             </xsl:when>
           </xsl:choose>
       </xsl:template>
```

How to do it correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, in the template that matches `Parametr1` you should combine the two `xsl:apply-templates` into one.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="Interposes[not(Representative)]/Accomplice
                             |Interposes/Representative"/>
```

In this case though, I have made a slight amendment to select the `Accomplice` element, and also only those which don't have a `Representative`

Doing this, then allows you to use the `position()` function to get the number. This will return the position of the various nodes (in document order) you have just selected.

To keep things tidy, I would have separate templates for `Accomplice` and `Representative` though....

```
<xsl:template match="Accomplice">
   <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
   <!-- Select either Person or Firm -->

<xsl:template match="Representative">
   <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
   <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
   <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ', Surname)"/>
```

Note you don't need full path to the element names in the match here. Also note you don't need the condition on the `Accomplice` in this case, as it will be selecting those elements where the condition is true.

It should now become a bit more straight-forward, with the only extra work being in the `Representative` template, to choose whether they are representing a firm or a person

```
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="../Accomplice/Person">
        <xsl:text>, representing a person: </xsl:text>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>, representing a firm: </xsl:text>
     </xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
```

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="text"/>

   <xsl:template match="Parametr1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Interposes[not(Representative)]/Accomplice|Interposes/Representative"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Accomplice">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
      <!-- Select either Person or Firm -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Representative">
      <xsl:value-of select="position()"/>
      <xsl:text>. </xsl:text>
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ', Surname)"/>
      <xsl:choose>
         <xsl:when test="../Accomplice/Person">
            <xsl:text>, representing a person: </xsl:text>
         </xsl:when>
         <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:text>, representing a firm: </xsl:text>
         </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="../Accomplice/*"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Person">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(Name, ' ', Surname)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Firm">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(FirmName, ' ', Description)"/>
      <xsl:value-of select="'&#10;'"/>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Notice the use of templates matching `Person` and `Firm` to allow them to be used in both the `Accomplice` and `Representative` templates.